# pd.cut categories as plt.xticklabels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some data, I am binning them using `pd.cut`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

garbage = 50*np.random.rand(100)

g=pd.DataFrame(data=garbage,columns=['a'])
g['a_binned'] = pd.cut(g['a'],bins=np.arange(0,100,5),labels=False)
g['a_binned_labelled'] = pd.cut(g['a'],bins=np.arange(0,100,5),labels=True)
```

then I group and I count

```
g_binned=g.groupby(['a_binned'])['a'].count()

plt.bar(g_binned.index,g_binned.cumsum().values)
```

I would like my xticklabels to be the strings with the values of `g['a_binned_labelled'].index`, so for instance `'(10, 15]', '(25, 30]'`

I would like to avoid using pandas plotting functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cut index is sorted ascendingly one may plot the bars against a range of numbers and set the ticklabels to the values of the index. This ensures to have the bars ordered correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

garbage = 50*np.random.rand(100)

g=pd.DataFrame(data=garbage,columns=['a'])
g['a_binned'] = pd.cut(g['a'],bins=np.arange(0,100,5), )
g_binned=g.groupby(g['a_binned'])['a'].count()


plt.bar(range(len(g_binned)),g_binned.cumsum().values)
plt.xticks(range(len(g_binned)), g_binned.index, rotation=90)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=90, ha="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with your comment, you have the better solution.  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston If [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10212) makes it into the next matplotlib release (2.2), one would be able to preserve the order of strings on axes. That would most probably let your solution work again.